# How to compare rows in a table and keep the highest values in the row in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I am looking for a query which will compare the current row value with previous row value and if the percentage of different between current and previous is less than 10% then keep the previous value. I am sure this can be achievable using oracle lag functions but I am unable to find the exact solution. I have tried below query but it is not keeping the previous value for future rows. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

I have used the below query to fetch the results but it didn't solve my problem.

```
select /*+ parallel(64) */ a, b, c, datevalue, pricevalue, 
        lag(pricevalue,1,0) over (partition by a, b, c order by a, b, c, datevalue) as prev_pricevalue,
        (pricevalue - lag(pricevalue,1,0) over (partition by a, b, c order by a, b, c, datevalue))/pricevalue as diff,
        case 
            when (pricevalue - lag(pricevalue,1,0) over (partition by a, b, c order by a, b, c, datevalue))/pricevalue
                  < 0.1 then lag(pricevalue,1,0) over (partition by a, b, c order by a, b, c, datevalue)
            else pricevalue
            end new_pricevalue
      from table1
      where datevalue between '18-MAY-2019' and '31-MAY-2019';
```

I have data like below. Column names are, A,B,C,DATE and VALUE

```
A               B       C       DATE        VALUE
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    18/05/2019  7.04
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    19/05/2019  7.04
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    20/05/2019  7.04
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    21/05/2019  7.04
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    22/05/2019  7.04
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    23/05/2019  7
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    24/05/2019  7
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    25/05/2019  7
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    26/05/2019  7
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    27/05/2019  7
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    28/05/2019  7
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    29/05/2019  8
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    30/05/2019  8
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    31/05/2019  8
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    01/06/2019  8.05
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    02/06/2019  8.05
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    03/06/2019  8.05
```

And, I want the output like below.

```
A               B       C       DATE        VALUE
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    18/05/2019  7.04
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    19/05/2019  7.04
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    20/05/2019  7.04
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    21/05/2019  7.04
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    22/05/2019  7.04
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    23/05/2019  7.04
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    24/05/2019  7.04
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    25/05/2019  7.04
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    26/05/2019  7.04
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    27/05/2019  7.04
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    28/05/2019  7.04
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    29/05/2019  8
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    30/05/2019  8
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    31/05/2019  8
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    01/06/2019  8
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    02/06/2019  8
16587EA_1005    RETAIL  7207    03/06/2019  8
```

Best Regards
MMR

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a concise method, but a recursive CTE can do this.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  -- adding a rank and rownum
  SELECT t.*
  , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a, b, c) AS rnk
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a, b, c ORDER BY datevalue) rn
  FROM table1 t
),
RCTE (rnk, rn, a, b, c, datevalue, pricevalue) AS
(
  -- seeding the recursion
  SELECT rnk, rn, a, b, c, datevalue, pricevalue
  FROM CTE
  WHERE rn = 1

  UNION ALL

  -- loop through the records for each rank
  SELECT c.rnk, c.rn, c.a, c.b, c.c, c.datevalue,
  CASE 
  WHEN ABS(r.pricevalue - c.pricevalue) / c.pricevalue < 0.1
  THEN r.pricevalue
  ELSE c.pricevalue
  END
  FROM RCTE r
  JOIN CTE c
    ON c.rnk = r.rnk
   AND c.rn = r.rn + 1
)
SELECT * 
FROM RCTE
ORDER BY rnk, rn;
```

**Returns:**

> ```
> RNK | RN | A  | B  | C  | DATEVALUE | PRICEVALUE
> --: | -: | :- | :- | :- | :-------- | ---------:
>   1 |  1 | a  | b  | c  | 18-MAY-19 |       7.04
>   1 |  2 | a  | b  | c  | 19-MAY-19 |       7.04
>   1 |  3 | a  | b  | c  | 20-MAY-19 |       7.04
>   1 |  4 | a  | b  | c  | 21-MAY-19 |       7.04
>   1 |  5 | a  | b  | c  | 22-MAY-19 |       7.04
>   1 |  6 | a  | b  | c  | 23-MAY-19 |       7.04
>   1 |  7 | a  | b  | c  | 24-MAY-19 |       7.04
>   1 |  8 | a  | b  | c  | 25-MAY-19 |       7.04
>   1 |  9 | a  | b  | c  | 26-MAY-19 |       7.04
>   1 | 10 | a  | b  | c  | 27-MAY-19 |       7.04
>   1 | 11 | a  | b  | c  | 28-MAY-19 |       7.04
>   1 | 12 | a  | b  | c  | 29-MAY-19 |          8
>   1 | 13 | a  | b  | c  | 30-MAY-19 |          8
>   1 | 14 | a  | b  | c  | 31-MAY-19 |          8
>   1 | 15 | a  | b  | c  | 01-JUN-19 |          8
>   1 | 16 | a  | b  | c  | 02-JUN-19 |          8
> ```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=384bf41f2907f0a15573e4f49024c891)*

Answer (score 1):

My attempt :) You can detect if change is greater than 10% and use new value there, in other cases leave null. Then use `lag` with `ignore nulls` clause:

```
select a, b, c, dv, pv, 
       nvl(cpv, lag(cpv, 1, cpv) ignore nulls over (partition by a, b, c order by dv)) new_pv
  from (
    select a, b, c, dv, pv, ppv, case when rn = 1 or abs((ppv - pv)/pv) > .01 then pv end cpv
      from (
        select a, b, c, datevalue dv, pricevalue pv, 
               row_number() over (partition by a, b, c order by datevalue) rn,
               lag(pricevalue) over (partition by a, b, c order by datevalue) ppv
          from table1))
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8d220398b0a563e7051b73612774e18f)</sup>**

It should be faster than @LukStorms recursive solution, which is good and works too.

Comment: Took me a bit to understand what's happening in that sql, but I think it's brilliant how your concept first sets that cpv to null for the threshold, then use the ignore null's in the outer query. And the trick to use connect for the sample data. Nice! :-) +1 Btw, 0.01 is only 1%?  Well, this should work for his data. But I wonder what the OP would expect when the data has a sequence like  7.5, 7.8, 7.0